# SQL multiple lookups for a single code column in an SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query an enterprise SQL Server

For whatever reason `claim_Id` and `Status_ID` are both contained in the same table i want to translate `claim_ID` and `Status ID` in the same query as separate columns how can I do this?

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║   claim   ║  code   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║ claim_ID  ║ code_ID ║
║ status_ID ║ name    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

`Claim` table:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗═════════╗
║  Claim_ID ║status_ID║Item_ID  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣═════════║
║ 1         ║ 12      ║  1      ║
║ 2         ║ 14      ║  2      ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝═════════
```

`Code` table:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║   CODE ID ║  name   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1         ║ complete║
║ 2         ║ cancel  ║
║ 12        ║  Open   ║
║ 14        ║Shipping ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Ideal output:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════ ╗════════════════
║   ITEM_ID ║Claim_ID_name║status_ID_name ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1         ║  complete   ║    open       ║      
║ 2         ║  cancel     ║    shipping   ║
║           ║             ║               ║
║           ║             ║               ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired output.  Most likely you will need to use `CASE` constructs.

Comment: Please describe better and show sample data

Comment: hey guys sorry about that im new to stack overflow tried to make it as clear as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sub query:

```
SELECT 
    ITEM_ID, 
    (SELECT name FROM Code WHERE CODE_ID = Claim_ID) AS Claim_ID_NAME, 
    (SELECT name FROM Code WHERE CODE_ID = status_ID) AS status_ID_name
FROM Claim
```

Comment: thanks for that Eric this proved to be the most efficient solution ive done a bit of research in sub queries as a result

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select item_id, code_table.name, sub_table.name
from claim_table, code_table, 
(select code_id, name
 from code_table
 ) sub_table                               
where claim_id = code_table.code_id
and status_id = sub_table.code_id;
```

You could also try to explore sub-queries:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could try this, but, I think @Eric's answer would perform faster for it consumes lesser cost.